# Autogenerate packages (folders) and classes with maven archetype

Tags: java, maven, maven-archetype

I want to automatically generate some packages and some templates of classes in maven archetype, based on some parameters.

Let's say I have specified them as:

```
<archetype-descriptor name="basic">
    <requiredProperties>
        <requiredProperty key="package_name"/>
        <requiredProperty key="class_name"/>
    </requiredProperties>
</archetype-descriptor>
```

And I want to automatically create class based on some template in the folder `/src/main/java/$package_name$`:

The template can look like:

```
package $package_name$;

public class $class_name$ {
   // some predefined structure...
}
```

Is it whether possible to do or not?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Yes. This is supported feature.

Check on this Baeldung post: [Adding Required Resources](https://www.baeldung.com/maven-archetype#3-adding-required-resources)

Comment: This article doesn't fully cover all topics (for instance, there is no description about how to generate proper package directory), but anyway it is pretty helpful. thanks

Comment: Please make the answer still valid without the broken link.